# How to check whether Compression on Oracle Table is working or not?

Tags: oracle

I want steps to in Oracle Database to find whether Compression is happening or not on a particular table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please perform below steps:

1. First execute analyze on your table.

   analyze table YOUR_TABLE_NAME compute statistics;
2. Execute below query to check the compression stats:

   select b.name, b.subname, a.AVGROWSIZE_NC, a.AVGROWSIZE_C,
   a.NBLK_NC, a.NBLK_ADVANCED, a.NBLK_EHCC, a.NROWS_NC,
   a.NROWS_ADVANCED, a.NROWS_EHCC
   from sys.compression_stat$ a, sys.obj$ b
   where a.obj# = b.obj#;
3. Execute the compression on your table
4. Analyze your table again (same first step)
5. Execute the SELECT query.. same as step 2nd.

Comment: cool. Let me check these steps.

Comment: Can you please tell what these column name means?